# Mac Codeblocks path

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks

I've been searching for about two hours and I can't find a solution. I installed codeblocks on mac and I can't read from a file. From what I saw, it's because codeblocks will run my program on my main user folder (where downloads,documents folders are). How can I make it to run from my project folder, because I don't want to use full path every time I use a file.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking: is it Code::Blocks that can't open the file or is it your program that you made with Code::Blocks that can't read files?

Comment: @DonaldDuck the problem is that if I create a file "input.txt" in the project folder and I use 'ifstream in("input.txt");' it isn't working. Because it's not looking for the file in the project folder and I want to know how to set that.

Comment: By *"project"* folder do you mean the folder where you have the compiled binary or the folder where you have the source code? Also how did you check which folder the program is trying to access?